# VLANs with managed and unmanaged switch

Tags: switch, vlan

[image: Different VLAN and unmanaged switch]

Is it possible to configure a network like shown in above diagram? I want to have 3 VLAN connected a unmanaged switch which is connected to a managed switch. I have created VLANs in this Multilayer switch, but I am not sure about the switchport mode of the connected Ethernet port.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no.  The unmanaged switch doesn't have the ability to create or trunk VLANs (if it did, it would be a managed switch).  It will treat all the PCs as if they were on the same VLAN.

If it were a mananged switch, you would configure the 3560 port as a trunk port.  But your unmanaged switch will not understand VLAN tagging.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the device you have. I know some cheap switches (~10-15 USD), that are "transparent" for vlans. In that case every vlan must be tagged on both sides (managed switch and computer).